# iOS App needs to POST to PHP script and then parse returned XML

Tags: php, iphone, ios, xml, parsing

I have a database of images stored in a table with columns such as "ImageName", "ImageCaption", and "EventName".

I wanna do a query and grab all images with a specific "EventName" - as selected by the user - like so:

```
$EventName = $_POST['EventName'];
$query = "SELECT * from ImageGalleryTable WHERE EventName = '". $EventName . "'";
```

The tricky part is that this user-selection is not coming from an HTML form, its coming from *within* an iPhone App. Here's my Objective-C code for that:

```
NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"EventName=%@", eventUserChose];
NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[myRequestString UTF8String] length:[myRequestString length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://mydomain.com/GetGalleryImages.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[returnData bytes]];
NSLog(@"responseData: %@", content);
```

All this works: the data I get back via `responseData` is good - its the XML generated by the PHP script I'm calling up top and everything is clean there. The POSTing from the App also works - so its all good.

So my question is this: how do I *parse* this sucker?

I've done tons of parsing using NSXMLParser (and yes, I know its not the best parser out there - lets please not get into *that* discussion here :-)) - but all the XML I parse usually comes ready from the server - its not dependent on any POSTed values, if you get my meaning. 
Usually I do the parsing like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mydomain.com/makeMyXML.php"];
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser parse];
```

And then I'm off and running. But here I gotta both POST something - which I think I can *only* do with the `NSURLConnection` code I included up top - and then I also have to parse it - which I usually do with the NSXMLParser code I included -- but they seem to conflict. I mean they *both* initiate a request process, don't they?

So how exactly should I be going about doing this? What's the correct way?

Comment: Just a comment: if your POST request won't create a resource, you should better use a GET request. IFF your query creates a resource, you should set the Location header in the response where the resource can be found. Otherwise, you are using HTTP the wrong way ;)

Comment: Good point! (force of habit... :-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other ways of creating an `NSXMLParser’, you want:

```
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:responseData];
```

So that you can supply the XML data that was downloaded.

Comment: oh, that's interesting - I didn't know you could do `initWithData:` in NSXMLParser. Good to know. And... it works! :-)  Thanks very much - will mark as correct answer :-)